# Using Field Calculator to correct the nomenclature of APN values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, string

I am currently working (in ArcMap 10.4) with two datasets that use different nomenclature for their assessor parcel numbers (APN) values. In one dataset the APN is a string dataset with the format "12345678". In the other dataset the APN is again a string but displayed as "123-456-78".

My goal is to add '-' characters to the correct position within the first string, to allow me to perform a join between the two APN fields respectively. Currently my script within the code block is seen below. I have created a new field titled "APN" and am hoping to populate this new field using the PRCL_ID string.

[image]

I am still not confident with scripting within the field calculator tool and have based this code on a similar problem in another thread. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the [da.UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) instead of Field Calculator. It will give you much more flexibility and is well worth learning. The code can be executed in the [Python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm) of ArcGIS.

```
import arcpy

feature_class = r'C:\database.gdb\feature_class' #Change to match your data
fields = ['field_to_read','field_to_write'] #Change to match your data

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = '-'.join([str(row[0])[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(str(row[0])), 3)])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Example from ArcGIS Pro but it is the same in ArcGIS Desktop:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this definitely solved my issue! I don't know why I was stuck on doing this in the field calculator. Having to use a "def" function was throwing me off.